# Cast de String para int Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, cast

Alguém sabe como faço um cast de `String` para `int` dentro da Query nessa pesquisa, a variável "searchString"?

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM StoreOrder s INNER JOIN s.user u WHERE lower(u.fullname) LIKE %:searchString% OR u.totalamount=:searchString")
public Page<StoreOrder> findBySearch(@Param("searchString") String searchString, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Esquisito usar o mesmo parâmetro como filtro de dois campos diferentes na query, não?

Answer (score 1):

O SQL do Hibernate (HQL) suporta *CAST* de maneira semelhante ao SQL nativo, com a diferença de que os tipos são os do Java e não os do banco de dados. Portanto:

```
u.totalamount = CAST(:searchString as Integer)
```

Comment: Olá Caffé, tentei fazer do jeito que me sugerium, mas está com a seguinte stack:                                  Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT s FROM StoreOrder s INNER JOIN s.user u WHERE lower(u.fullname) LIKE :searchString OR u.totalamount = CAST(:searchString as Integer)]. 
[93, 106] The state field path 'u.totalamount' cannot be resolved to a valid type.

Comment: Imagino que você tenha este erro mesmo sem o CAST. Será que a entidade `user` possui um campo `totalamount`? Será que este campo é do tipo Integer? Será que este campo pertence na verdade à StoreOrder e portanto deveria ser prefixado com **s** (`s.totalamount`)?

Comment: Sim, estou tendo esse erro mesmo sem o cast, e exite esse campo, do tipo Integer, vou tentar adicionar um parâmetro a mais no método, mas do tipo Integer, quero ver se o erro continua ...